# Using json with jquery Ajax doens't return anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I wanted to learn how to use JSON with jQuery so I followed a simple video tutorial on it. However, after following all the steps and using the exact same code as in the video, I still don't see anything in the console after a console.log. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $.ajax({
      url: 'articles.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'get',
      cache: false,
      succes: function(data) {
        $(data.articles).each(function(index, value) {
          console.log("success");
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my JSON file (articles.json) from which I am trying to use the data:

```
{
    "articles": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Article 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Article 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Article 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You spelled `success` incorrectly. See docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Do you create HTML file and json file under the same path, and then open the page throuth browser? This is because XMLHttpRequest cannot load file through File location. I suggest you to put this two files under some web Project and accessing them through HTTP. For example, localhost:8080/youAPP/page.html

Comment: @charlietfl I'm sorry, it's written like that in my native language :)

Comment: The property name must be correct. Can misspell whatever you want in the logging statement, that's not relevant to the problem

Comment: @charlietfl Oh thank you, I thought you were talking about the console.log("success"); , it didn't fix my problem though :/

Comment: Then add an eror handler and find out more from that. Can also inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. Are you opening this page from a web server...localhost or other?

Answer (score -1):

Here is correct way to read json data in javascript using jquery

```js
<script>
    $.ajax({
      url: 'articles.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'get',
      cache: false,
      succes: function(data) {
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
   $.each(jsonData.articles, function(i, v) {
    console.log("id = "+ v.id);
    console.log("name = " + v.name);
           });
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use $.getJSON

example

```js
$.getJSON( "articles.json", function( data ) {
 
  $.each( data.articles, function( key, val ) {
   console.log(val);
  });

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: While this is a different solution, it doesn't answer the OP's problem where he misspelled success.